Why am I getting a 404 Not Found error when accessing a specific todo item in Strapi?
I am working on a Strapi project where I manage a list of todos through the API. However, when I try to access a specific todo item using its ID, I get a 404 Not Found error.
API Endpoints
Fetching All Todos:
URL: http://localhost:1337/api/todos
Response:
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "documentId": "rd9kcz2j4297jwlaaul6546r",
            "title": "Implement Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) Pipeline for Enhanced Workflow Automation",
            "description": "Set up a CI/CD pipeline using GitHub Actions to streamline our deployment process, ensuring that all code changes are automatically tested and deployed to production.",
            "completed": true,
            "createdAt": "2024-10-13T20:12:43.251Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-10-13T20:12:43.251Z",
            "publishedAt": "2024-10-13T20:12:43.215Z",
            "locale": null
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": 6,
            "documentId": "h2c9dht299krwf5fttyy80gv",
            "title": "Set Up Application Monitoring and Logging for Improved Issue Tracking",
            "description": "Implement monitoring and logging tools to track application performance and errors in real-time, facilitating faster troubleshooting and resolution of issues.",
            "completed": true,
            "createdAt": "2024-10-13T20:32:53.550Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-10-13T20:32:53.550Z",
            "publishedAt": "2024-10-13T20:32:53.547Z",
            "locale": null
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 6
        }
    }
}

Fetching a Specific Todo:
URL: http://localhost:1337/api/todos/1, Method GET
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": {}
    }
}

Troubleshooting Steps Taken

I verified that the todo with ID 1 exists in the database by checking the response from the /todos endpoint.
I ensured that I am using the GET method for the request.
I checked the API permissions in the Strapi admin panel and confirmed that the Public role has access to the findOne action for todos.
I tested the URL directly in Postman.

Question
Despite these checks, I am still receiving a 404 Not Found error when trying to access http://localhost:1337/api/todos/1. What could be the reason for this, and how can I resolve it?

Never mind, saw the solution there
just using documentId instead of id
